# Confusing behavior when starting new activity with PendingIntent

Tags: android

I am using BroadCast Listener to listen to incoming phone stat then pushing a Notification like this:

```
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Contact: " + number;
    CharSequence contentText = "Call From: " + number;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CallHandler.class);

    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.NUMBER, number);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.STATE, stat);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.NAME, name);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.DURATION, duration);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.START_TIME, startTime);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notif);
```

So when there are multiple calls, I expect to have multiple call notification and when I click each notification, I expect to start an activity with the attached parameters. However, I can see that the Activities that starts later, gets the Intent of the previous call.

Here is how I am looking into intent from the Activity

```
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String number = extras.getString(KEYS.NUMBER);
    // String state = extras.getString(KEYS.STATE);
    long duration = extras.getLong(KEYS.DURATION);

    Date start = getStartDate();
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.subject)).setText("");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_time)).setText(tf.format(start));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.end_time)).setText(tf
            .format(getEndDate()));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caller_number)).setText(number);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.notes)).setText(getNotesDefaultContent(
            number, duration, start));
```

How can I keep the intents separately call independent activity?

Comment: I had the same problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340431/how-can-i-correctly-pass-unique-extras-to-a-pending-intent still havent been able to figure it out

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Notice the last parameter of the PendingIntent.getActitity method.
If you'd like to know which FLAG you should use, see the API documents - 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int)][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int)

~Dolph~

Comment: Its PendingIntent not PendintIntent

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved even more easily... simply overide `onNewIntent(Intent intent)`
 method in activity class and just add `startactivity(intent)` inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I'v found a solution. The trick is to create the Intent properly!

Here is my working code:

```
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Contact: " + number;
    CharSequence contentText = "Call From: " + number;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CallHandler.class);


    notificationIntent.setAction("com.vantage.vcrm.android.telephony"+System.currentTimeMillis());//unique per contact


    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.NUMBER, number);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.STATE, stat);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.NAME, name);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.DURATION, duration);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(KEYS.START_TIME, startTime);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationIntent, 0);

    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notif);
```

You see, I am setting unique Action in my intent by doing this:

```
notificationIntent.setAction("com.vantage.vcrm.android.telephony"+System.currentTimeMillis());//unique per contact
```

Also I am sending unique requestor ID in the pending Intent:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationIntent, 0);
```

This resolved the problem.