# How to detect sender of notification sent by NotificationManager / detect which notification at the Notification Bar has been clicked?

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I am working on a GPS app. My app will fire notification by NotificationManager if the user go inside or outside a predefined zone. My app can fire notification for both cases.

From onResume(), I always get the latest intent.setExtra() value instead of of intent.setExtra value of the clicked notification.

> > > The problem is how to detect the user click on the notification for inside zone or outside zone? (I want to show different view on different case)
> > >
> > > Is it possible to add a listener for notification clicked?

Here is my code spinet:

```
private void displayNotificationMessage(String message, boolean vibrate, boolean playSound, Intent contentIntent, String notificationTag)
{       

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.buslogo, message, System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(),0, contentIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Friendly Reminder", message, myPendingIntent);

    contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    if (vibrate)
        notification.vibrate=new long[] {100L, 100L, 200L, 500L};

    if (playSound)
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;


    notification.number = ++notificationCounter;
    notificationMgr.notify(notificationTag, notificationCounter, notification);

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent( Intent intent ) {
    Log.i( TAG, "*********** onNewIntent(), intent = " + intent );
    if (intent.getExtras() != null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "in onNewIntent = " + intent.getExtras().getString("test"));
    }
    super.onNewIntent( intent );
    setIntent( intent );
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "*********** Main - onResume()");

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if (intent.getExtras() != null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "test = " + intent.getExtras().getString("test"));
    }
}

public void createNotification(String msnContent)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, Main.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
    bundle.putString("test", msnContent);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    displayNotificationMessage(msnContent, true, true, intent, "test"); 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a listener for notification clicked?

Use a different `PendingIntent` for each case. If you are only changing an extra, be sure to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` when creating the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my code. I pass a new PendingIntent object to notification.setLatestEventInfo() every time before I send the notification by notificationMgr.notify(). But it still cannot distinguish which notification at Notification Bar has been clicked. Since onResume() always return the latest setExtra() value.

Comment: Is it any way to pass value/object from original activity to the intent called by Notification?

Comment: @user767987: "Since onResume() always return the latest setExtra() value." See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089698/get-the-intent-that-woke-up-my-activity/6089739#6089739

Comment: Thanks again. I have read the link that you provided and add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to the intent that passes to PendingIntent. But I found that onNewIntent( Intent intent ) still get the latest intent that I passed to notification.setLatestEventInfo(). Anything goes wrong? or is there any other way to distinguish which notification at the Notification Bar has been clicked?

Comment: @Android Beginner: "But I found that onNewIntent( Intent intent ) still get the latest intent that I passed to notification.setLatestEventInfo()." -- this is precisely what you want.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to always get the latest intent that I pass to notification.setLatestEventInfo(). I want to get different intent for different Notification at Notification Bar. What I was trying to do is use the intent that passed to onNewIntent( Intent intent ) to distinguish which Notification has user clicked.

Comment: @Android Beginner: Use `PendingIntents` that are substantially different (e.g., different action strings) for your two `Notifications`. Then, the `Intent` passed to `onNewIntent()` will tell you what you want to know.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. I solved problem by adding intent.setAction()

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from this post - [Confusing behavior when starting new activity with PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472447/confusing-behavior-when-starting-new-activity-with-pendingintent/5013713#5013713). Also, thanks to the help from CommonsWare.

I was missing intent.setAction().

Below is the code spinet of detect which notification at the Notification Bar has been clicked. Hope it can help someone else who has the same problem.

```
package com.NotificationTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = Main.class.getSimpleName();
    int notificationCounter =0;
    private NotificationManager notificationMgr;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        notificationMgr =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(
                NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationMgr.cancelAll();

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setText("B1");
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                createNotification("From B1");
            }
        });


        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b2.setText("B2");
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                createNotification("From B2");
            }
        });
    }


    private void displayNotificationMessage(String message, boolean vibrate, boolean playSound, Intent contentIntent, String notificationTag)
    {       

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, message, System.currentTimeMillis());


        contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(),0, contentIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Friendly Reminder", message, myPendingIntent);



        /*if (vibrate)
            notification.vibrate=new long[] {100L, 100L, 200L, 500L};

        if (playSound)
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;*/


        notification.number = ++notificationCounter;
        notificationMgr.notify(notificationTag, notificationCounter, notification);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent( Intent intent ) {
        Log.i( TAG, "*********** onNewIntent(), intent = " + intent );
        if (intent.getExtras() != null)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "in onNewIntent = " + intent.getExtras().getString("test"));
        }
        super.onNewIntent( intent );
        setIntent( intent );
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "*********** Main - onResume()");

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        if (intent.getExtras() != null)
        {
            String extraOfClickedNotification = intent.getExtras().getString("test");

            Log.i(TAG, "test = " + extraOfClickedNotification);

            if (extraOfClickedNotification.equals("From B1"))
            {
                // Do something
            }
            else if (extraOfClickedNotification.equals("From B1"))
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }

    public void createNotification(String msgContent)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(msgContent + System.currentTimeMillis());
        intent.setClass(this, Main.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
        bundle.putString("test", msgContent);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        displayNotificationMessage(msgContent, true, true, intent, "test"); 

    }

}
```