# How can i create same pendingIntent for canceling the alarm from different activities?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am storing tasks in database with unique ID. And there are 4 different activities that insert and/or delete tasks from database. Now I want to set alarm for these tasks with task_id as request code in PendingIntent. The alarm set from any of the 4 activities. And when task is deleted then Can I cancel the alarm using the task_id (request code).

As I have mentioned alarm has to be set and cancel from 4 activities, I want to make set and cacek alarm as Util function so that I can avoid code duplication.

Comment: this might help-->   [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204075/static-alarmmanager-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the PendingIntent you have created using the unique task_id(Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int)). Now cancel the Alarm using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)