# Send String from Appwidget to New Activity

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I'm working on an `appWidget` which has a `textView`, all i want is preview this `textView` in a new activity that i launch with

```
Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, ViewFromWidget.class);
configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);   
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetLayout, myPendingIntent);
```

Can some one point me out on how can i send a string to the new activity that u start via appWidget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be easy, you want to use an [intent extra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for passing strings.

Add this before setAction

```
   configIntent.putExtra("MyKey", myString);
```

And in the activity getting the intent use [getStringExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

```
   String passedString = getIntent().getStringExtra("MyKey");
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but the new activity displays nothing,! am i missing something friend?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340431/how-can-i-correctly-pass-unique-extras-to-a-pending-intent. This might be an issue with the extras not being properly set on a pending intent.

Comment: Awesome! `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` did the job... Thanks for your help...

Comment: @Wesley PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT fixed it for me! Thanks a lot, i spend few hours trying to figure out why it wasnt working!