# Activity triggered by a click on a Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

From a `Service`, I trigger a `Notification` which, when clicked, has to launch an `Activity`. To do this, I use the following code :

```
    notification=new Notification(icone,title,System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),myActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("org.mypackage.name",true);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),title,"Message",pendingIntent);
    notification.flags|=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
     ((NotificationManager)contexte.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify("label,0,notification);
```

When I click on the `Notification`, the `Activity` is correctly launched. But it's `Intent` doesn't contain the extra boolean added with the line `intent.putExtra("org.mypackage.name",true);`.

Does anyone have an idea of this behaviour?

I can add that I use Android 4.

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: in my experience sometimes intent doesn't send other type. pls, check intent.putExtra("org.mypackage.name", "true"); and in myActivity getIntent().getStringExtra("org.mypackage.name");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340431/how-can-i-correctly-pass-unique-extras-to-a-pending-intent) says that if you don't set an `Action` on your `Intent` that the extras won't be passed along.  SO you should try that.