# Make changes to another class from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alarms

I have a an Activity A, and a class B(extends BroadCastReceiver). From A, I am making an alarm like this:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerAlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
            time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), 3000, pendingIntent);
```

and this this B(name is TimerAlarmReceiver):

```
public class TimerAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    public static long TIME;
    public static Boolean TimerOn=false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm went off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("Tag", Long.toString(TimeKeeper.Time));
    }
    public static void setTime(long T)
    {           TIME=TimerActivity.DMILLIS;         
    }
}
```

What I want to do is access something like a static variable from onReceive. I tried making a public static member in the activity.The logs show the correct set value for as long as the app runs. But if  I force quit the app, the log in onReceive becomes 0.

So how do I pass an Initial value to B ? Something that keeps the value even if the app is closed(force quit).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as one of the extras of the Intent you use to create the `PendingIntent`. It will then be delivered to your `BroadcastReceiver` and you can extract it there.

Another option is to [store it somewhere](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: I tried putting intent.put extra, but it does not seem to work. could you give the code to me ?

Comment: @harvey_slash Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5256680/82788). You might need to specify an action for the extras to work.