# Android 7 BroadcastReceiver onReceive intent.getExtras missing data

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-7.0-nougat

My app isn't working on Android 7.  My BroadcastReceiver.onReceive method is called but the contents of the intent.getExtras is missing.  I've verified that the data was correctly loaded.  Here's a snippet from my onReceive method, where intent is passed as a parameter to onReceive.

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
textMessage = bundle.getString("TEXT_MESSAGE");
ArrayList<MyPhoneNumber> phoneNumbersToText = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("PHONE_NUMBERS");
```

Both textMessage and phoneNumbersToText are null.

Here's a snippet from my manifest file:

```
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="com.friscosoftware.timelytextbase.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Here's a snippet where the data is loaded:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context , AlarmReceiver.class);  
intent.putExtra(Constants.TEXT_MESSAGE, scheduledItem.getMessageToSend());
intent.putExtra(Constants.PHONE_NUMBERS, scheduledItem.getPhoneNumbersToText());    

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, getRequestCodeFromKey(key), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Get the AlarmManager service
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, selectedDateTime.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

The same code works fine in Android 6.

Any thoughts on what changes are required here for Android 7?

Thank you

Comment: Intent has the setAction(String action) method. You can paste the serializable object here. It works. Set extras won't work in Android 7. I had the same problem. Here is the sample - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54718479/4516797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1, it looks like you're having the same issue as me. I logged it on the tracker, (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216581) which you commented on.

My solution was to use SharedPreferences to store my custom object. Then, when the alarmmanager fires, I run the following to get the object out.
tl;dr, I use GSON to serialize/deserialize my custom POJO in/out of SharedPrefs as a String. For example:

```
 String json = getSharedPrefs(context).getString(NotificationUtility.NEXT_REMINDER_KEY, "No reminder found");
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Reminder reminder = gson.fromJson(json, Reminder.class);
        if (reminder != null) {
            return reminder;
        }
    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error parsing json: " + error.getMessage(), error);
        return null;
    }
    return null;
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out your suggestion.  Hopefully, a fix will be forthcoming.

Comment: Your solution worked, but for other reasons I decided to store the data in a database and simply pass the key.

Comment: So according to the bug report it's intended behaviour... Wait what?

Answer (score 10):

Android O version doesn't get extras properly in BroadcastReceivers. But the one great solution is to use an intent's **setAction(String action)** method to send the serializable **Alarm** object. Then get it back to object in **onReceive**.
Here is the sample:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(new Gson().toJson(alarm));
```

Then in your Alarm's receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String alarmSerializable = intent.getAction();
    if (alarmSerializable != null)
        alarm = new Gson().fromJson(alarmSerializable, Alarm.class);

    //TODO next, send notification
}
```

This is the common way for Android O and others.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but I think I found an easy solution. Put your data inside a Bundle and send that Bundle with your alarm intent. In my case I wanted to send a serializable object with my intent.

Setup the alarm:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
`
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

// creating an example object
ExampleClass exampleObject = new ExampleClass();

// put the object inside the Bundle
bundle.putSerializable("exapmle", exampleObject);

// put the Bundle inside the intent
intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);

PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// setup the alarm
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

Receive the alarm:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // get the Bundle
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
        // get the object
        ExampleClass exampleObject = (ExampleClass)bundle.getSerializable("example");
    }

}
```

It worked fine for me. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Looks promising but since the data was already being stored in a database I decided to simply pass the key.  Thanks

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks. Very clear and straight forward.