# Android cannot pass intent extras to AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649728/android-cannot-pass-intent-extras-though-alarmmanager) would solve my problem, but it doesn't.

I have this code to send my alarm:

```
public void triggerAlarm() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("Id", nextDue.id.get() + "");
    String passed = intent.getStringExtra("Id");
    Log.d("DEBRRUG", "The extra im passing: " + passed);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), i++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, soonest.dueTime.get(), pendingIntent);
}
```

My DEBRRUG statement indicates that the extra being passed is 8.

This is my alarm receiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String passed = intent.getStringExtra("Id");
        Log.d("DEBRRUG", "The extra im receiving: " + passed);
    }
```

Here, my DEBRRUG statemnt indicates that the extra im receiving is NULL.

Note: Something that could, possibly, be interesting is that my triggerAlarm method is being called from within my ContentProvider. Don't know if that helps you understand my problem better or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39573849/1979882

Comment: I saw that, but I'm not doing anything with parcleable objects....??

Comment: I can't see something wrong inside your code. That's why I've just wrote in comments. This is not an answer. just a suggestion to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use 
intent.getExtras().getString("id")

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Wow! I was sending another alarm in another area of my code, where I wasn't putting the extra on.

Doing ctrl f -> ".set(Alar" let me track down the little bastard.